# Crystal Reports Filter Parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, crystal-reports

I would like to filter a parameter based on other values. So the situation is. I want to show only neighborhoods belonging to a certain city, and only if they have games happening certain days.

I'm hoping i do something like the following, this is a bit of a mix of powershell and sql because I don't really know sql as well as I'd like.

```
foreach ($N in db.Neighborhoods) {
   if (db.city = "denver"){
      if (db.eventdate in {?start_date} to {?end_date}){
         {?Neighborhood} =+ $N
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You want to replicate same in crystal formula?

Comment: I just want to do what ever it would take to make the {?neighborhood} parameter only display results that belong in say denver and had events between the two dates given.

Comment: Parameter doesn't display any results it is just used to take the input from user... you need to manipulate the input to display result.. now what are you looking for?

Comment: I want a dynamic parameter that will only display neighborhoods in which are located in a given city and has events between the given dates. When I attempt putting in the report select statement something like

Comment: You need to use dynamic cascading parameters

Comment: Is there a way to do that with dates? For instance saying it must have an event date between {?start_date} to {?end_date}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Record Selection Formula`

in that write like below.

```
datedatabasefield > {?Start Date} and 
datedataabsefield < {?End Date}
```

Along with this your can add other filtering criteria aswell